# Debugging an MVP UserForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba, mvp

New to VBA and I'm attempting to create a form using the MVP format however I can't seem to get things to communicate properly. Below is (in order) the code for the Class(Model), the Form (View), and the Module(Presenter). The current goal is to get the Module to write the PO Number in A1 to validate that everything communicates like it's supposed to.

The Class(Model)

```
    Option Explicit

Private Type DEFClass
    PO As Integer
End Type

Private this As DEFClass

Public Property Get PO() As Integer
    PO = this.PO
End Property

Public Property Let PO(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.PO = value
End Property
```

The Form (The View)

```
Option Explicit
Private Type DEFView
     Model As clsEntry
End Type

Private this As DEFView

Public Property Get Model() As clsEntry
    Set Model = this.Model
End Property

Public Property Set Model(ByVal value As clsEntry)
    Set this.Model = value
End Property

Public Function PONumContent() As Integer
    this.Model.PO = PONumber.Text
End Function

Private Sub Submit_Click()
    PONumContent
     SortPO
End Sub
```

The Module (The Presenter)

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub SortPO()
    Dim m As clsEntry
    Set m = New clsEntry
    With New DataEntryForm
    Set .Model = m
    Range("A1") = m.PO
End With
End Sub
```

Current error is "Object variable or With block variable not set" for "this.Model.PO = PONumber.Text" within the View/Form.

Comment: The code as you show doesn't throw that error. However, I assume that you have some more code in the form module, eg an `UserForm_Activate`  that accesses the model before it is assigned.

Comment: Forgot to mention: You can easily debug your code and see how and when things are called. You just need to enable debugging in classes: In the VBA editor, use *Tools->Options*, switch to the *General* Tab and select *Break in Class Modules* under  *Error Trapping*.

Comment: So going step by step. It starts with the SortPO Sub, runs until Set .Model = m, bounces to the form's Public Property Set Model, bounces *back* to the Range(A1) from the Sub, finally goes to the Class's Get PO and then ends that with statement. I can't seem to get it to return to the this.Model.PO. I've tried changing that line to a public sub and even changing the Class's Get PO as this.Model.PO

Comment: I don't see `PONumber` defined, so my guess is that you believe it's one of the controls on the form. Make sure each form control name is spelled correctly and see if that's the issue.